# PHP, Reading Text File For String

Tags: php, string

i am trying to read a text file and find out if there is a string in there. i have tried many different ways. this is what i have so far,

```
$file = "./userpass.txt";
$loginuser = $_POST[loginuser];
$loginpass = $_POST[loginpass];
$fileauth = file_get_contents($file);

if (strpos($file,$loginuser) !== false and strpos($file,$loginpass) !== false)  {
    echo 'Incorrect Password';
} else {
    echo 'Hello The Master';    
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$loginuser = $_POST[loginuser];
$loginpass = $_POST[loginpass];
```

to

```
$loginuser = $_POST['loginuser'];
$loginpass = $_POST['loginpass'];
```

and this code reads file contents

```
    $fileName   = "newfile_testing.txt";        
    $file_handle= fopen($fileName , "r");

    $theData    = fread($file_handle, filesize($fileName));

    print_r($theData);
```

Comment: For simplicity reasons, PHP has `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error. Fix it first. `$_POST[loginuser];` should be `$_POST['loginuser'];` and `$_POST['loginpass'];`. In `strpos()` `$file` should be `$fileauth`.

```
$file = "./userpass.txt";
$loginuser = $_POST['loginuser'];
$loginpass = $_POST['loginpass'];
$fileauth = file_get_contents($file);
if (strpos($fileauth,$loginuser) !== false and strpos($fileauth,$loginpass) !== false)  {
    echo 'Incorrect Password';
}else {
    echo 'Hello The Master';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are trying to find the user/password combination in the `filename` of that particular file (`$file`) instead searching against it's contents (`$fileauth`):

```
 if (strpos($fileauth,$loginuser) !== false and strpos($fileauth,$loginpass) !== false)  {
```

As noted by @Please Wait in his answer (nice catch), you also need to reference the `$_POST` indexes as a string, so

```
$loginuser = $_POST[loginuser];
$loginpass = $_POST[loginpass];
```

should be :

```
$loginuser = $_POST['loginuser'];
$loginpass = $_POST['loginpass'];
```